# How to create a new map column from an existing struct column based on another column list values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[image]

I have tried creating UDF by sending listColumn and Struct column like below but unable to create map column

```scala
val MyUDF1: UserdefinedFunction = udf((listCol: Seq[String], dataCol: Seq[Row]) => ??)
```

Basically i want to fill the `??` part which I'm unable to complete

Comment: Hello, please don't share data as screens, just copy and paste it. Also, be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way your input data is displayed, both `listColumn` and `structColumn` are lists of strings. If that's not the case, the following will probably not work. When using lists as input of UDFs, you need to use the `WrappedArray` type as follows:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
val df = Seq(
    (Seq("col1", "col2"), Seq("a", "b", "c")),
    (Seq("col2", "col3"), Seq("a", "b", "c"))
).toDF("listColumn", "structColumn")

val myUDF = udf((listCol : WrappedArray[String], structCol : WrappedArray[String]) =>
    (0 until scala.math.min(structCol.length, listCol.length))
        .map(i => listCol(i) -> structCol(i))
        .toMap
)

df.withColumn("mapColumn", myUDF('listColumn, 'structColumn)).show(false)
```

```
+------------+------------+----------------------+
|listColumn  |structColumn|mapColumn             |
+------------+------------+----------------------+
|[col1, col2]|[a, b, c]   |{col1 -> a, col2 -> b}|
|[col2, col3]|[a, b, c]   |{col2 -> a, col3 -> b}|
+------------+------------+----------------------+
```